# Pricing equation with two correlated states

Tags: brownian-motion, asset-pricing, geometric-brownian, pde

Consider the following asset pricing setting for a perpetual defaultable coupon bond with price $P(V,c)$, where $V$ is the value of the underlying asset and $c$ is a poisson payment that occurs with probability $\lambda$.

Both $V$ and $c$ evolve as geometric Brownian motions, potentially correlated with:
$$\frac{dV_t}{V_t} = \mu_V dt + \sigma_V d Z^V_t$$
$$\frac{dc_t}{c_t} = \mu_c dt + \sigma_c d Z^c_t$$
and $Corr(d Z^V_t, d Z^c_t) = \rho dt$.

I believe the pricing equation for the bond looks like:
$$\frac{\sigma_V^2}{2}V^2 P_{VV} + \rho \sigma_V \sigma_c V c P_{Vc} + \frac{\sigma_c^2}{2}c^2 P_{cc} + \mu_V V P_V + \mu_c c P_c + \lambda c= rP$$

I'm guessing that the solution for this equation is:
$$P = A_0 + A_1 V^{\gamma_1} + A_2 V^{\gamma_2} + A_3 c^{\gamma_3} + A_4 c^{\gamma_4}$$

Is the above correct?

Comment: I don't understand, if $c$ is a Poisson payment why does it follow a diffusion process? I'd like to try to answer your question but I am still very confused: 1. What do you actually mean with a perpetual defaultable coupon bond, 2. what is the underlying $V$ exactly, and 3. why is the coupon rate stochastic? And lastly, 4. isn't it the default process that is a Poisson process instead of the coupon (process)?

Comment: Thanks! 1. There is no time derivative in the pde. 2. Does not matter, it only gives rise to the ito terms of  the pde. 3. This is just an assumption, can take  $\lambda$ as a parameter and  $c$ as an additional state variable for the problem. 4. No, the default interpretation only affects boundary conditions. To clarify, I believe the pde to be correct, I'm not sure how to solve that. The guessed solution does not work.